# Permission denied when using IMGKIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, permission-denied, imgkit

I am using IMGKIT for creating image from HTML but getting error Errno::EACCES
i.e Permission denied for folder in which I want to store image.

I have tried chmod/chown

owner of folder and user who is running nginx is same

Is there any conf / setting to set the destination folder

O/P of ls -l (I want to store image in img_kit folder)

***drwxrwxrwx 2 xxx xxx 4096 Apr 30 12:00 img_kit***

Comment: In rails, you should always store files within public folder. What is the full path of your folder?

Comment: path = #{Rails.root}/public/img_kit